# Moment without time output date type not string

Tags: momentjs

```
var moment = require('moment');
var c = moment().toDate();
```

How to output date without time in this format **`DD-MM-YYYY`**

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to output the date in the format DD-MM-YYYY, simply use

```
var moment = require('moment);
var c = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY");
```

`toDate()` converts the moment instance into a JS date, which it doesn't sound like you want to do.

I would advise looking at the [Moment documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/) for questions like this, it's very detailed and easy to understand.